# How to set div inside iframe without an src attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

iframe without an src attribute. I want to set the div inside iframe without src but it seems difficult for me. My html code is

```html
<div class="demo-wrapper">
  <iframe src="">
    <div>
      <p>Hello World</p>
      <p>Hello World</p>
      <p>Hello World</p>
      <p>Hello World</p>
      <p>Hello World</p>
      <p>Hello World</p>
      <p>Hello World</p>
      <p>Hello World</p>
      <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting a div element inside of an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29571365/inserting-a-div-element-inside-of-an-iframe)

Comment: Also possible duplicate of [Insert content into iFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795761/insert-content-into-iframe)

Comment: Why would you want to do this? an Iframe is meant to insert a piece of another website inside yours. An empty (no src) iframe is useless.

Comment: @LuukSkeur i will use it a scrollspy or scrollbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be achieved using JavaScript. Check below example.

```js
var html = document.getElementById("iframeCont").innerHTML;
var iframe = document.getElementById("myiframe");
iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(html);
```

```html
<div class="demo-wrapper">
  <iframe id="myiframe" src="">
  </iframe>
  <div id="iframeCont" style="display: none">
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <p>Hello World</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a typo in the result? This code is outside of the iframe, not in it as the OP requested...

Comment: @patrick : The code outside is just a container to hold the data. It's been copied to the iframe using JS.